# Powershell Create CSV of files with "_lowRes.jpg" of a certain file size

Tags: powershell, csv, search, directory, filenames

I am trying to create a CSV file of all jpgs in a directory and its sub-directories that are above 100 KB and have the suffix "_lowRes.jpg".

Want to use Powershell.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy actually!

You'll do this with two separate filters, which PowerShell achieves via the `Where-Object` cmdlet.  This cmdlet accepts comparisons in the format of `{$_.PropertyName -eq "Something"}` or `PropertyName -eq "Something"`.  The later format is only available on PowerShell v3 and up.

First, to filter to only files above 100KB.

`Where-Object Length -ge 100KB`

The second part, where the filename contains something.

`Where-object Name -like "*lowRes.jpg*"`

You could join them, but I would just pipe one into the other, like this.

`dir *.jpg -Recurse | Where-Object Length -ge 100KB | Where-object Name -like "*lowRes.jpg*"`

You might want to put the Name filtering first, because less files will have a certain name than be above or below a certain size.  Depends on how your files are laid out.

Finally, pipe all of that into the `Export-Csv` cmdlet and bam, you're done!

Comment: Is there a reason that you split your `Where` statements, or is it just personal preference? `<fanboy>`Also, just wanted to say I'm a huge fan of your series on how to make a GUI and threaded scripts blog posts. `</fanboy>`

Comment: I split them because you can't join where statements and maintain the new easy to read syntax. I love the new syntax, so I add the tiny inefficiency of using two separate commands. Some disagree and that's fine but I just find it easier to read and interpret. And I'm happy you like the site. Let me know if you'd like me to cover a certain topic :)

Comment: you can do : where {$_.Length -ge 100KB -and $_.Name -like "*lowRes.jpg"}       i doubt for performance if you use 2 where. Filter can be use in gci command, its better for performance. If you have a directory whith name "toto.jpg" you command take it too

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply like this :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -Recurse -file -filter "*_lowRes.jpg" | 
                 Where Length -ge 100KB | select fullname, Length |
                                export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoType
```

short version (for no purist) :

```
gci "C:\temp" -Rec -file -filter "*_lowRes.jpg" | ? L -le 100KB | select fu*, le* | epcsv "c:\temp\result.csv" -Not
```